# how to use Peer-To-Peer networking to minimize internet bandwidth?

Tags: networking, windows-7, p2p, content-management

I am trying to build a networking solution to the following problem:

I have several stores running PCs which need to be frequently updated with new content (primarily video files ~40Mb).  I want to put the new content on a central server and have the PCs pull down the files.  I can write services to run on the PCs that will take care of contacting the server and downloading the content.  But, I have to find a way to minimize the total bandwidth used.  The PCs are connected to the internet but not on a domain, they are mostly Windows 7 Home/Premium editions.

If each PC connected only to the central server I would not be taking advantage of the fact that the neighboring PC (within the same store, on the same router) may already have the new files.  Ideally, that PC would be able to discover this and rather than getting the files from the central server it would get them from its neighbor.  The files are not secure and speed is only a minor concern.

At first though a Peer-To-Peer service would be at the heart of this solution.  But, I don't know anything about Peer-To-Peer application development or where to start.
If you have any ideas of where to start with such a solution or any thoughts on how I could solve this problem I'd love to hear it!

Thank You, Jesse D.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to develop your own thing, just set up a (private) bittorrent tracker on your central server and point all the PCs to it to download the update.

You may even be able to use [Murder](https://github.com/lg/murder), developed by Twitter for the very purpose of distributing updates to numerous machines.

Comment: would to solve the root problem which is to minimize internet bandwidth used?  In other words, would the PC connect to its neighbor within the LAN or would it go out and back in?  Thanks.